# Focus the first Window Where pcmanfm is Running

Tags: debian, window-management, xdotool, wmctrl, pcmanfm

From the command line, what is the best way to locate the first window where `pcmanfm` is running, and then give that window focus?

`pcmanfm` does not showcase it's application name on the title bar of the window in which it is running, so you can't focus it using `wmctrl -a pcmanfm` (which works for me in other applications that do indeed showcase their application's name in the window title bar).

This is just one example, but what I'm really looking for is a better method of locating windows that are running a particular command, and then giving that window focus. The title bar method I've been using just isn't always reliable.

Comment: I found this [video](https://youtu.be/AK2UKUfsV3g?t=641) that covers a more reliable technique.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pcmanfm`'s window class to activate it:

```
wmctrl -xa pcmanfm.Pcmanfm
```

Or move it to the current desktop and activate it *or* start it there:

```
wmctrl -xR pcmanfm.Pcmanfm || /usr/bin/pcmanfm
```

Maybe you'll find my short shell script [activate-or-start.sh](https://gist.github.com/brothert/76d26a71d76938c43d7694e184b4c428) useful. It tries to find and activate a window matching a pattern (by title, window class or binary path) and it starts an application if the window isn't found.